# dblclick() on floating div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a large background div, on which i have bound a function via the jQuery function dblclick.

I have an absolutely positioned div with a greater z-index floating infront of said background div. And I am getting a weird issue where if the floating div (which does have a filled background) is double clicked, the function set for the background is executed.

Basically:

```
$("#background-div").dblclick(function(){
  alert("why do these problems exist?");
});

//i double click on $("#div-floating-in-front") and see the alert.
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? I'm having trouble visualising it... =/

Comment: Is the floating `div` within the html `div` tags of the clicked one?

Comment: Please share your HTML with us as well so we can evaluate the full problem.

Comment: Yes, my div was contained in the background div, and that was the issue. See `@j08691`'s answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your floating div is a child of the background div then the click event is bubbling up to it and triggering the alert. You can attach a click event to the floating div and then use [jQuery's stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to catch the click before it can bubble up:

```
$("#div-floating-in-front").dblclick(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```